# webpart with rounded corners - SharePoint 2010

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a solution using Jquery.corners for my webparts to have rounded corners.
Any ideas preferable one that doesn't need images.
Any ideas and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Check this post out on how to style Web Parts: http://www.sharepointdesigners.net/profiles/blogs/webpart-title-bar-with

Comment: Thanks Wictor.But don't think this will work for SP 2010

Comment: Methinks the link is broken.